# How to read different blocks from a single csv into different arrays?

Tags: python, csv, numpy-ndarray

My textfile consists of different "blocks", e.g.,

```
0 0 1
1 1 1
1 0 0

1 0 0 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 0

1 0 0 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 0
1 0 1 0

1 0 0
0 1 1
1 1 1

1 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 0 0
1 1 0 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 0 0
```

I want to read each block in a np array.
I didn't find a parameter for`np.loadtxt()` to read within blank lines.
I guess imposing conditions at `f = open('test_case_11x5.txt', 'r') for line in f: ...` is slow.

Does anyone know a neat method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution using `re.split` and a small list comprehension. I assumes the full text is first loaded in the variable `text`:

```
import re, io
import numpy as np

# text = ... ## load here your file

[np.loadtxt(io.StringIO(t)) for t in re.split('\n\n', text)]
```

output:

```
[array([[0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0.]]),
 array([[1., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0.]]),
 array([[1., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0.],
        [1., 0., 1., 0.]]),
 array([[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]]),
 array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.]])]
```

Comment: What's the rational in using `re.split()` over just `str.split()`?

Comment: @BTables `split` is perfectly fine, just the habit on my side I guess ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `groupby` function in `itertools` like this:

```
from itertools import groupby
import numpy as np

arr = []
with open('data.txt') as f_data:    
    for k, g in groupby(f_data, lambda x: x.startswith('#')):
        if not k:
            arr.append(np.array([[int(x) for x in d.split()] for d in g if len(d.strip())]))
```

This will yield a list of np arrays.